# SQL Query Result to PowerShell object

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell

I'm looking for a way to map a query result, which I'm receiving from my orchestrator runbook. I need to map this query result into a PowerShell object to work with it.

The query result looks like this:

```
9;Taskname;username;09.06.2017 00:00:00;10;3,24;Taskname2;username2;21.07.2017 00:00:00;0;7,25;taskname3;username;31.08.2017 00:00:00;0;7,
```

the query shows following:

```
ID;Taskname;username;datetime;progress;projectid,
```

I get this result with this query from orchestrator:

```sql
SELECT [id]
  ,[name]
  ,[ressponsible]
  ,[targetdate]
  ,[progress]
  ,[projectid]
FROM table WHERE progress < 100 and targetdate < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE);
```

The result is a string as shown above.

I'm currently using this PowerShell Code:

```
#declare variable

$a = "\`d.T.~Ed/{F60295A1-775D-4D61-9A73-5A180446F4EF}.QueryResultString\`d.T.~Ed/";

$a | out-file c:\users\admwid\desktop\test.txt
```

Inside the Microsoft Orchestrator it looks like this:

[image]

This is just an idea. I appreciate every input, like if it makes more sense if i do the query inside the PowerShell.

After mapping this output to a PowerShell object I have to sort it by the username, so I can work with the result.

Comment: Please edit the question and describe how you get the result. How to process the result depends pretty much on the access method. If it's via ADO, you got a nice result set. If it's via mysql client, it's a text string.

Comment: Please show your PowerShell code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my problem. For now i wrote the whole script in PowerShell and will add a Mail-function to distribute the information to all responsible. I got a couple of tasks wich belong to different Users. I check wich tasks belongs to wich user (it can be more than 1 task per user) and send one mail with every task listed.

The Script looks like this so far (without the mail-function)

```
<#define SQL credentials#>
$dataSource = “SERVERNAME”
$user = “USERNAME”
$pwd = “PASSWORD”
$database = “”
$connectionString = “Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;”

<#connect with SQL Server#>
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$connection.Open()

<#define and execute query#>
$query = “SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[responsible]
      ,[targetdate]
      ,[progress]
      ,[projectid]
  FROM TABLENAME WHERE progress < 100 and targetdate < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE);”

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()

<#map result to table#>
$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($result)

$format = @{Expression={$_.Id};Label=”Id”;width=10},
            @{Expression={$_.name};Label=”Name”; width=30},
            @{Expression={$_.responsible};Label=”Username”; width=30},
            @{Expression={$_.targetdate};Label=”datetime”; width=30},
            @{Expression={$_.progress};Label=”progress”; width=30},
            @{Expression={$_.projectid};Label=”projectid”; width=30}

$table | Format-Table $format | Out-File C:\Users\username\Desktop\table.txt

<#close connection#>
$connection.Close()

<#define variable expired tasks#>
$expiredTasks = $table;

<#get unique username#>
$uniqueUsernames = $expiredTasks | Sort-Object -Property responsible -Unique | select responsible

<#foreach username get all expired tasks#>
foreach($uniqueUsername in $uniqueUsernames)
{
    <#select task where username foreach username#>
    $selectTasks = $table | Where-Object -Property responsible -Like $uniqueUsername.responsible

    sendMail $selectTasks
}
```

If anyone knows a better solution for this case, I'm open minded